# how to change font size of JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class trial2 
{   
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String[] option = {"Chorita M. Adlawan", "Noel B. Angeles", "Julie P. Benenoso", "Percival P.Bermas", 
            "Beverly Mae M. Brebante","Adela N. Cabaylo", "Carol G. Cainglet", "Oscar U. Cainglet", 

    String selected = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "MINES AND GEOSCIENCES BUREAU - REGION XI, DAVAO CITY\n" +
            "                         LIST OF REGISTERED EMPLOYEES", 
            "Please Select Employee",JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, null, option , "Adlawan");     

}
}
```

Those are my codes above.  My question is, can i change the font size and style of my JOptionPane to make my list font larger, very much appreciated for any tip. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you want all `JOptionPane`s to have the same font style and size, you can change the property of the `UIManager` with:

```
javax.swing.UIManager.put("OptionPane.font", new Font("yourFontName", Font.BOLD, 30));
```

To get a list of the available font names, use the following snippet:

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
String[] fontNames = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();

for (int index = 0; index < fontNames.length; index++)
{
     System.out.println(fontNames[index]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways is to use HTML directly in the String literal. For example:

`"MINES AND GEOSCIENCES BUREAU - REGION XI, DAVAO CITY\n"`

Can easily become:

`"<html><span style='font-size:2em'>MINES AND GEOSCIENCES BUREAU - REGION XI, DAVAO CITY"`

Note that when you use HTML, you can no longer use `\n` for new lines. Use `<br>` instead.

Comment: what if i wanted to also change font style, is there a way to do this using HTML? Thanks.

Comment: If by style, you mean bold and italics, then yes, you can. You can use a surprisingly large subset of HTML. For example, you can create tables, and so on.