# How to change font with showconfirmdialog?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, joptionpane

I have tried many different tutorials and none have worked this is what I have. Any help?

```
UIManager.put("OptionPane.font", new FontUIResource(new Font("Press Start 2P", Font.PLAIN, 11)));

if (questionNumber == questions.size()) {
    triviagui.questionFrame.setVisible(false);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your score for this level was : " + levelScore + " out of 10. \n Your total score is " + triviagui.totalScore, "Scores", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, pokeballIcon);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to change font size of JOptionPane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724686/how-to-change-font-size-of-joptionpane)

Comment: `new Font("Press Start 2P", Font.PLAIN, 11)` does that work in a plain `JLabel`?  For better help sooner, post a [MCTaRE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Tested and Readable Example).

Answer (score 2):

this is how I change my font in a JLabel, so maybe it is any help?

```
message = new JLabel(textMessage);

// create bigger text (to-times-bigger)
Font f = message.getFont();
message.setFont(new Font(f.getName(), Font.PLAIN, f.getSize()*2));
// put text in middle of vertical space
message.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
```

You just take the font from your label, and reset the font as you like.
Maybe you can do the same with your JDialog?

---

I found a working answer here: [formatting text in jdialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008100/formatting-text-in-jdialog-box)

this could be a method called by the actionListener of a button:

```
public void openPopUp(){
        String t = "<html>The quick <font color=#A62A2A>brown</font> fox."; 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, t);
    }
```

Gives you this result:
[image]