# Changing font of JTextArea in JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jtextarea, joptionpane

I'm just wondering if you can somehow change the font of the text in `showMesaggesDialog` by using `area.getText()` (area is what i call for my `JTextArea`) so far i have tried this but no luck.

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {     
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String myString=area.getText();
        Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
        area.setFont(font);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f.getComponent(0),myString);
    }
});
```

Comment: The answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724686/how-to-change-font-size-of-joptionpane) might help.

Comment: @resueman nope not working  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
           // String myString=area.getText();
            Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
            area.setFont(font);
            javax.swing.UIManager.put(area.getText(), new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 30));
           
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f.getComponent(0),area.getText());

Comment: Don't put code in comments where it is unreadable. Instead edit the question using the link below the topic tags. General Tip: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than calling JOptionPane.showMessageDialog with a String, use a JLabel.

Try this:

```
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {     
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        String myString=area.getText();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(myString);
        Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 12);
        label.setFont(font);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(f.getComponent(0),label);
    }
});
```

Comment: it works and what i wanted to do now is to get all the font(which i have done) when someone presses ok the font will change